# CLOB Performance Issue in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, clob

I've created the below function . When we write SQL queries using this function, the query returning 10K records is running for a very long time 2 hours. I figured out the performance Issue is due to CLOB usage in the function.  When I change the CLOB reference in the below type and function to Varchar2 the query runs in a sec.

But, I don't want to change the data type to Varchar2. I wanted to have it as CLOB. But how can I improve the performance?

I do understand that I can go with LISTAGG or other oracle provided string functions. But I wanted the data type as CLOB and wanted to know, why there is such a huge difference in execution.

Below is the code of the User Defined Function. The query sample is given below.

```
select my_concat(col1),my_concat(col2),my_concat(col3),my_concat(col4) from table group by col1,col2,col3,col4;





  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "my_concat"                                          
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS OBJECT (
   curr_str   clob,
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT my_concat)
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   my_concat,
      p1     IN       varchar2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       my_concat,
      returnvalue   OUT      clob,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   my_concat,
      sctx2   IN       my_concat
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/



CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY "my_concat" 
IS
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT my_concat)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      sctx := my_concat (NULL);
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   my_concat,
      p1     IN       varchar2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         curr_str := curr_str || ',' || p1;
      ELSE
         curr_str := p1;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       my_concat,
      returnvalue   OUT      clob,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      returnvalue := curr_str;
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   my_concat,
      sctx2   IN       my_concat
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (sctx2.curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         SELF.curr_str := SELF.curr_str || ',' || sctx2.curr_str;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
END;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func_cat (p1 varchar2)
   RETURN clob    
   AGGREGATE USING my_concat;
/
```

Comment: If it works with varchar, why do you need/want CLOB? Or did you only test the varchar version (or built-in listagg) with a small subset of data - which would make the timing comparison unhelpful?

Comment: Try `IN OUT NOCOPY` for parameters